# JavaScript into Asp Page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i am learning javascript client side scripting language and i am using js in ASP.. i dont know when i compile the code, it shows

> COMPILATION ERROR:Compiler Error
>   Message: CS1061: 'ASP.default_aspx'
>   does not contain a definition for
>   'popup' and no extension method
>   'popup' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'ASP.default_aspx' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or
>   an assembly reference?)

here is my code :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WEB_test_app._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Shuraat Web ki</title>
    <script type ="text/javascript">
    function popup()
    {
    alert("popup!!");
    }    
    </script> 
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick ="popup()"/>

      <script type ="text/javascript">
      document.write("Abid");
      </script>   
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can somebody edit the code :/.. please..

Comment: i dont know how to edit.. :/ sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're confusing client-side and server-side events. The `popup()` function is written in Javascript and runs on the client, but [OnClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclick.aspx) is a server-side event, so its handler runs on the server and has to be written in the language of your page (C#). `popup()` has no meaning in that context.

You can use the [ClientClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick.aspx) event in order to handle the button click client-side. Note that you probably should return `false` from the handler in order to avoid a postback to the server:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"
    OnClientClick ="popup(); return false;" />
```

Comment: what do i do if i wish to write the same code on server side?

Comment: @Abid, what do you intend to accomplish by showing a modal dialog box *on the server*? :)

Comment: umm.. :) i dont know..  i was just trying things without thinking what i want to do actualy :)

Comment: actually, i am a newbie.. i just try and try and try.. i dont exactly know what to do..

Comment: @Abid, well, you *could* handle the click event server-side (using `OnClick`), but then `popup()` should be written in C#, and should register a script to call `alert()` on the client when the page has finished loading. Check out [RegisterClientScriptBlock()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bahh2fef.aspx) for the gory details.

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign `popup()` to the event `OnClientClick` instead of `Click` like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick ="popup()"/>
```

The reasoning behind your problem is that when the run-time saw `OnClick` it tried to attatch that event with a C#/VB.Net (Code-Behind) method (which obviously does not exist) and we solved that by attaching the event `OnClientClick` to your Javascript method.

Answer (score 1):

`OnClick` - is click handler on **server side**. If you want to call javascript function, use `OnClientClick`.